# How to store IPFS hash on ink! smart contract?

Tags: ink

I'm working on an ink! smart contract that will store the IPFS hash for each `AccountId`. I see that in EVM it's efficient to convert the hash to bytes32. What about in ink!, is `Vec<u8>` efficient enough?

```rust
#[ink(storage)]
pub struct MyContract {
    cids: Mapping<AccountId, Vec<u8>>,
}
```

Comment: I think we can also use `Hash` instead of `Vec<u8>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the IPFS hash is fixed length (32 bytes), you can use `[u8; 32]` array instead of `Vec<u8>` which is more efficient.